# Unable to install turicreate in Ubuntu 18.04 Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

Running "pip install turicreate" but I am getting error.

Python 3.7.3
Ubuntu 18.04

```
pip install turicreate

Collecting turicreate
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/54/167837569bcb816b3fe68f003f18d07ab9d5ac31b2b12b8f9b07b1ccc7a4/turicreate-4.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: turicreate
  Building wheel for turicreate (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-b9l56kf5/turicreate/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-2550m_rm --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install


          ==================================================================================
          ERROR

          If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
          for your system. Supported platforms are:

          * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
          * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
          * Python 2.7, 3.5, or 3.6.

          Other possible causes of this error are:

          * Outdated pip version (try `pip install -U pip`).

          ==================================================================================



  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for turicreate
  Running setup.py clean for turicreate
Failed to build turicreate
Installing collected packages: turicreate
  Running setup.py install for turicreate ... error
    Complete output from command /venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-b9l56kf5/turicreate/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-3rpmjewn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /venv/include/site/python3.7/turicreate:
    running install


            ==================================================================================
            ERROR

            If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
            for your system. Supported platforms are:

            * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
            * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
            * Python 2.7, 3.5, or 3.6.

            Other possible causes of this error are:

            * Outdated pip version (try `pip install -U pip`).

            ==================================================================================
```

Comment: From your error: "Supported platforms are ... Python 2.7, 3.5, or 3.6" but you are using python 3.7...

Comment: Is there any way to install it. Or any alternative for turicreate ? @FlyingTeller

Comment: How about a virtual env with python 3.6 in it? Refer to [this github issue](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/788) for python 3.7 support

Comment: @FlyingTeller Sure I will try it . Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should use pip3 for python 3.7

## python 2.7

```
python file_name.py
pip install "module name"
```

## python 3.7

```
python3 file_name.py
pip3 install "module name"
```

Comment: OPs posted output shows that `python 3.7` is used just as expected. You don't always have to write `pip3` or `python3` if the `python` that is first in your `PATH` already is python 3x